# Convert normal web service to wcf

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a normal web service.  Many java and .net users are accessing it.  Can I update it to wcf without anyone having to change their code?  Any tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use WCF with Basic binding. It supports non-wcf clients with "legacy asmx" (is this what you call normal web service?).